# Xcode7, iOS9 use of unresolved identifier 'EKSpanThisEvent'

Tags: swift2, xcode7, ios9, xcode7-beta5

i got a problem with this code

```
import UIKit
import EventKit

let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(EKEntityType.Event, completion: { (success, accessError) -> Void in
        if accessError != nil {
            print("Calendar Access Error: \(accessError)")
            return
        }
        let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

        event.title = self.detailItem!.title
        event.allDay = true
        event.startDate = self.detailItem!.date
        event.endDate = self.detailItem!.date
        event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
        var saveToCalendarError: NSError?
        let success: Bool
        do {
            //Swift2: use of unresolved identifier 'EKSpanThisEvent'
            try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: EKSpanThisEvent)
            success = true
        } catch var error as NSError {
            saveToCalendarError = error
            success = false
        } catch {
            fatalError()
        }
```

the compiler does not compile, and the error is "use of unresolved identifier 'EKSpanThisEvent'"

i hope someone can help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 2 / Xcode 7 a lot of enumerations have been changed for consistency

```
try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
```

Answer (score 1):

Better if you handle the errors thrown by `saveEvent`:

```
do {
    try store.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
} catch let specError as NSError {
    print("A specific error occurred: \(specError)")
} catch {
    print("An error occurred")
}
```

More about Error Handling in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3

```
do {
   try self.eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
} catch let specError as NSError {
   print("A specific error occurred: \(specError)")
} catch {
   print("An error occurred")
}
```